# She comes up rudely with me vs She behaves rudely with me

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning

Once my colleague said to me that she comes up rudely with me but i said to her she behaves rudely with me, would be suitable to say. So, which one is the best to use? Thanks

Comment: Your question is twofold. One is about judging the acceptability of your alternatives. The other is asking about a preferred choice. I'd rather leave the former to native speakers. As for the latter, my natural choice would be an obvious one: *She was rude to you*.

Comment: It is possible the coworker might have said "she comes up rudely with me", but it's not really fluent.  Is it possible the coworker said "she comes up rudely **to** me"?  To "come up to someone"  means to approach them.

Comment: Good questions like this one don't *come up* too often. If you check the definitions of [come up](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/come-up) you will see that the meaning is different.

Answer (score 3):

"She comes up rudely with me" is not something a fluent speaker would say. Forget that one.

"She behaves rudely with me" is possible. It's grammatically correct and makes sense. It's a little awkward because the word "behaves" is not really necessary. Rudeness is a behavior, so you don't need to explain that it's a behavior. That said, people do fairly often say that someone is "behaving rudely".

A fluent speaker would normal say, "She is rude to me", or "She is being rude to me".

Answer (score 3):

If you mean she gives the *impression* of being rude, regardless of whether she actually is rude, then you could use:

> She **comes across** as rude to me.

See [come across](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_across):

> 1. (idiomatic) To give an appearance or impression; to project a certain image.
>      *A business suit and briefcase help her to **come across** as the competent professional she is.*

Comment: This makes sense! I wasn't able to come up with any reason why the example sentence uses *comes up*. I think they meant *comes across* indeed.

Comment: Good point. "Comes up" is an idiom meaning "happens unexpectedly" or "happens occasionally". Like, "Oh yes, problems like this sometimes come up when you are trying to do this job." Or, "I have to cancel my appointment. Something important came up." "Comes across" is an idiom meaning "seems" or "appears". That is, if I say "She comes across as rude" I am not saying that she IS rude, but that appears to be rude. The implication is that she is not necessarily trying to be rude. This may be an accident caused by her unfamiarity with local customs or some such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know it:

- She is rude to me (if constantly)
- She is being rude to me (if usually she is polite, and being rude is not natural behavior for her)

Comment: +1, but a quibble: "She is being rude to me" says that she is being rude on this particular occassion. It doesn't really say what her natural behavior is. She might normally be polite. She might always be rude. You may never have met her before. It just says, she's being rude on this time.